# заполнение массива в js

Tags: javascript, jquery

добрый день.
есть несколько таблиц в html через jqery хочу перенести их все в массив и отправить на сервер.
таблицы успешно перебираются и данные заносятся в массив, но во все массивы заносятся данные только последней таблицы. как можно сделать, чтобы этого не происходило.
код ниже.

```
var allData = new Array();
var TableData = new Array();

var AllTable = $("Table");

AllTable.each(function(rows, Ctable){
        $(Ctable).find('tr').each(function(row, tr){
        TableData[row]={
            "id" : test($(tr).find('td:eq(0)').attr("id"))
            , "from" : $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text()
            , "till" :$(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text()
            , "where" : $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text()
            , "who" : $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text()
    }); 
    TableData.shift();  
    allData[rows]=TableData;
    console.log(TableData);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша `TableData` - это все время один и тот же массив. Создавайте новый массив на каждой итерации внешнего цикла.

```
AllTable.each(function(rows, Ctable){
  TableData = [];
  ...
```

Comment: Блин. точно. Огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: @DenisGorynin На здоровье. Галочка - слева от ответа. Успехов.

Comment: да, пока не дает поставить. 10 минут времени.